# Android looper loop runs indefinitely on android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-looper

The following method call does not terminate within a separate thread in my application.

> Looper.loop();

I'm not able to diagnose why this occurs. Any suggestions?

Comment: it loops the separate thread, so how can it hang the main UI thread?

Comment: Apologies it was actually caused by having a semaphore lock the main thread. I've edited the question.

Comment: http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#123

Comment: Hi there I'm not sure what I should be seeing over there? If it's the facts that it's an infinite for loop, correct. But the loop should terminate once no messages are left in the que, should it not?

Comment: why should it terminate?

Comment: It should terminate because the que is finite, and hence line 127 should execute?

Comment: line 127 is reached when you call Looper.quit(), otherwise loop() - as its name suggests - loops forever